# What theorem tells us that a function has a power series expansion around a point?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, power-series

I'm trying to show that $(1+z)^a$ has power series expansion around $z=0$. What theorem could I use to directly prove this?

Comment: $(1+z)^a$ has power series expansion around $0$ if and only if it's holomorphic at $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A holomorphic function (defined and $\mathbb C$-differentiable on an open subset of $\mathbb C$) necessarily has a power series expansion around every point of its domain. The radius of convergence is at least the distance to the exterior of its domain.

That's the case of your function, if $a$ is a positive integer, that's a polynomial which is obviously holomorphic on $\mathbb C$. If it's a negative integer, holomorphic on $\mathbb C^*$, and if it's an arbitrary real, then you need to define it using a complex logarithm, making it holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R_-$.

Comment: Gotcha; so there isn't a theorem name or anything i could simply state that would suggest that the function is holomorphic? Or would this just be saying Cauchy-Riemann as a contender if I was really trying to prove that it's holomorphic

Comment: This theorem doesn't have a name but has a nice shorthand "holomorphic functions are analytic" together with its own wikipedia page.

Comment: Also, if $a$ is a positive integer, you don't need all this complex analysis machinery, the power series expansion is finite and explicit through the binomial theorem.

Comment: the $a$ is a complex exponent in my case, I've posted other similar questions related to this to kind of lead me to finding the correct power series representation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That a function which is holomorphic in a domain $\Omega$ has a power series expansion in every disk $B_R(a) \subset \Omega$ is an immediate consequence of [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

This can be seen as follows: For $0 < r < R$ and $|z-a| < r$ is
$$
 f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|w-a|=r} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} \, dw \, .
$$
Now
$$
\frac{1}{w-z} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}}
$$
converges uniformly on $|w-a|=r$, so that integration and summation can be exchanged:
$$ \tag{$*$}
 f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n 
$$
where
$$
 a_n =  \frac{1}{2 \pi i }\int_{|w-a|=r} \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} \, .
$$
It follows that $f$ can be expanded into a power series in $B_r(a)$.

This holds for all $0 < r < R$ and power series coefficients are uniquely determined. Therefore $(*)$ holds in the disk $B_R(a)$.